Let $\{ a_n \}_n$ be a sequence such that $a_n < \frac{a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}}{2}$. Prove that it is convergent
Let $\{a_n \}_n$ be a sequence such that $a_n \geq 0 \, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and
$$
a_n < \frac{a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}}{2}
$$
Prove that $\{ a_n \}_n$ is convergent
My attempt: I tried to prove that the sequence is finitely bounded: otherwise if $\sup\limits_n a_n = +\infty$ then we would get that
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} a_n < \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}}{2} \implies +\infty < +\infty$$ which is an absurd.
After that I am completely stuck: I have tried to use Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem (because now that I have proved that it is bounded, then I know that it exists a convergent subsequence) and to show that every subsequence converge to the same $L \in \mathbb{R}$ hence $\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} a_n = L$ (by an unnamed theorem taken from the same book where I found this exercise).
Someone has any hints to help me solve this exercise?

If $a_n < b_n$ then the best you can hope for is $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n \leq \lim_{n\to\infty}b_n.$ Taking limits converts $<$ to $\leq$.

Does $n <n+1$ give $+\infty <+\infty$?

@geetha290krm you're right. I'll think for another way to prove that it is bounded

Your sequence is bounded from below by 0 according to your data.
$a_n<\frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}}{2}, \forall n\in N$
$a_n\geq 0, \forall n\in N$.
Take:
$a_{n+1}<\frac{a_n+a_{n-1}}{2}<\frac{\frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}}{2}+a_{n-1}}{2}=\frac{2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}}{4}<\frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}}{2}$
This implies that $a_n<a_{n-2}$ since all numerators are non negative.
So we have two covering subsequences:
$a_1, a_3,...,a_{2k-1},...$
$a_2, a_4,...,a_{2k},...$
Both are monotonically decreasing and bounded from below by 0.
Then we have both partial limits 0.
Since these subsequences cover the sequence. this is the only limit.

Ahem. $a_n=a_0$ for all $n$ is  a solution with non zero limit.

There seems to be an error in your calculation, $\frac{\frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}}{2}+a_{n-1}}{2}=\frac{3a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}}{4}$, not $\frac{2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}}{4}$
